# How to select an item by its ID and not by its index position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
username  45michael  7762hc  adrian12  alicia7   
product                                                                                       
63767           0.0     0.0       0.0      0.0           
76863           1.0     0.0       0.0      0.0        
84325           0.0     0.0       0.0      0.0         
86217           0.0     0.0       0.0      1.0
```

I'm trying to perform KNN on it and return recommendations given a product id, my question is how can I **select an item** in the DataFrame **by product** (i.e: I want product 84325), I mean, how can I get the index position of that item to pass it into the function. So for item 84325 I want to get 2.

Comment: [`Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)?

Comment: Something like: `df.index.get_loc(84325)` ?

Comment: `df.loc[84325]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta that just returns me this: 
`username
45michael    0.0
7762hc       0.0
adrian12     0.0
alicia7      0.0
angel8       0.0
john5        0.0
kerrigan     0.0
kylemm       0.0
uololo       0.0
yvera        0.0`